# what is double(::) in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

While going through some of the angular best practices guide I found this concept of using `::` before models for uni-direction binding. But it seems does not work with `input` field. Here is an example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/gZ73PNGGg4m45zFuBYZw?p=preview

Inside expression it works as expected but inside ng-model, it's still 2-way binding. Then what's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An expression that starts with :: is considered a one-time expression.
>   One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable,
>   which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a
>   non-undefined value (see value stabilization algorithm below).

You can read more about [`::`](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html)

For your requirement, you can just use ng-value

Here is a [`sample`](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZMO7wQQ6rxwPZ2XSVSSi?p=preview)

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="name">
 <input type="text" ng-value="name">
```

Comment: `::exp` will not work for ng-model inside a input box? Because in my example its still updating the `<input type="text" ng-model="::tc.name">` where as I was expecting that it will not update

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy No you can't check this sample https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/pw9nct1w/3/